# Добавить в option selected через js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html-select

Как подставить в `option` `selected`, используя JavaScript?

У меня подгружаются данные о пользователе через JavaScript в виде JSON, пробую сделать подстановку к `select` вот так:

```
$('option[data-add-lids=' + data.options_staff.add_lids + ']').selected;
```

Судя по отказу кода работать, это неправильное решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня вот так работает, попробуйте:

```
$('option[data-add-lids=' + data.options_staff.add_lids + ']').attr("selected","selected");
```

Comment: Точно! Забыл, что надо два раза писать =)

Comment: Лучше использовать `.prop()`.

Comment: @Etki, в принципе да, но я встречал немало проектов, где jquery 1.6-